# How to find point along line defined by two points?

Tags: google-maps, geometry

There is a function in google maps geometry library

```
interpolate(from:LatLng, to:LatLng, fraction:number)
```

which finds a point between two other points:

```
A--X--B
```

I need something very similar, find a point further along the line:

```
A--B--X
```

Interpolate does not accept fraction>1 so I cannot use it. Is there some simple way to calculate the point?
 I want to achieve given distance between A and X points.

EDIT: In my application the distance was really small so I used fromLatLngToPoint conversion and linear interpolation, which get good enough results on small area.

Comment: If you know the distance beyond point b then all you need is the bearing from point a to point b and add on the extra distance to return the coords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate bearing, then find destination point with code from [this excellent page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)